# Google Play Feature Graphic download

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

Google Play application on mobile devices, has the Feature Graphic at the top of selected application view.

Unfortunately it isn't shown on the play.google.com website. e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android

Is it possible to obtain this graphic without using Google Play mobile application?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, its bit of hackish and very simple

1. get to know the package name , here which is `com.instagram.android`
2. in google image search , search for this name
3. in size settings, make it exact 1024*500
4. Bang on! The first image you'll get is 99% the feature image

:D enjoy

Comment: Unfortunately it works only with very popular applications.
E.g. for pl.tribalddb.mcdonalds.app.android the result is really surprising.